# Converting raw SQL Query to Laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to convert or improve a raw query to laravel's eloquent. It involves nested select and it honestly looks confusing to me.

I tried doing it directly in laravel first but I figured I could probably make a raw SQL first and convert it which I'm failing miserably right now.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM `posts`, (
SELECT `highs`.`id` AS hid, `lows`.`id` AS lid, (`highs`.`up_votes_1` + `highs`.`up_votes_2` + `highs`.`up_votes_3` + `lows`.`up_votes_1` + `lows`.`up_votes_2` + `lows`.`up_votes_3`) AS reacts
FROM `highs`, `lows`
WHERE `highs`.`post_id` = `lows`.`post_id`) AS react
WHERE `posts`.`id` = `react`.`hid` AND `posts`.`id` = `react`.`lid`
ORDER BY `reacts` DESC
LIMIT 5
```

This query already works and it returns the data I needed, I just need it converted to eloquent.

Comment: https://pontaku-tools.com/english/

Comment: Please use the eloquent relationship to achieve this. There is no way to convert row into eloquent. Please take a look at https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships

Comment: Hello, I did have relationships in my app. Basically, I have a `post` model which `hasOne` `high` and `hasOne` `low` if that helps.

Comment: Sometimes the easiest method is creating an SQL view and creating a read only eloquent model.